# update SQL table from foreign data source without first deleting all entries (but do delete entries no longer present)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a bunch of MySQL tables I work with where the ultimate data source from a very slow SQL server administered by someone else.  My predecessors' solution to dealing with this is to do queries more-or-less like:

```
results = python_wrapper('SELECT primary_key, col2, col3 FROM foreign_table;')
other_python_wrapper('DELETE FROM local_table;')
other_python_wrapper('INSERT INTO local_table VALUES() %s;' % results)
```

The problem is this means you can never use values in local_table as foreign key constraints for other tables because they are constantly being deleted and added back into the table whenever you update it from the foreign source.  However, if a record really does dis sapper in the results to the query on the foreign server, than that usually means you would want to trigger a cascade effect to drop records in other local tables that you've linked with a foreign key constraint to data propagated from the foreign table.

The only semi-reasonable solution I've come up with is to do something like:

```
results = python_wrapper('SELECT primary_key, col2, col3 FROM foreign_table;')
other_python_wrapper('DELETE FROM local_table_temp;')
other_python_wrapper('INSERT INTO local_table_temp VALUES() %s;' % results)
other_python_wrapper('DELETE FROM local_table WHERE primary_key NOT IN local_table_temp;')
other_python_wrapper('INSERT INTO local_table SELECT * FROM local_table_temp ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE local_table.col2 = local_table_temp.col2, local_table.col3 = local_table_temp.col3
```

The problem is there's a fair number of these tables and many of the tables have a large number of columns that need to be updated so it's tedious to write the same boiler-plate over & over.  And if the table schema changes, there's more than one place you need to update the listing of all columns.

Is there any more concise way to do this with the SQL code?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into replication?

Comment: If you mean replicating the foreign, slow database, in a less ad-hoc manner, no that's not something I'd thought about.  Unfortunately, in my case, I don't think it's a practical solution for a lot of reasons:

Comment: For one, the foreign database is Oracle and the local database is MySQL.  Locally, we don't have the resources to replicate the full, foreign SQL server.  Or, for that matter, to license and run an Oracle database server.

Answer (score 0):

I have a somewhat un-satisfactory answer to my own question.  Since I'm using python to query the foreign Oracle database and put that into SQL, and I trust the format of the table and column names to be pretty well behaved, I can just wrap the whole procedure in python code and have python generate the update SQL update queries based off inspecting the tables.

For a number of reasons, I'd still like to see a better way to do this, but it works for me because:

1. I'm using an external scripting language that can inspect the database schema anyway.
2. I trust the database, column, and table names I'm working with to be well-behaved because these are all things I have direct control over.
3. My solution depends on the local SQL table structure; specifically which keys are primary keys.  The code won't work without properly structured tables.  But that's OK, because I can restructure the MySQL tables to make my python code work.

While I do hope someone else can think up a more-elegant and/or general-purpose solution, I will offer up my own python code to anyone who is working on a similar problem who can safely make the same assumptions I did above.

Below is a python wrapper I use to do simple SQL queries in python:

```
import config, MySQLdb
class SimpleSQLConn(SimpleConn):                                                                         
    '''simplified wrapper around a MySQLdb.connection'''                                                 

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):                                                                        
        self._connection = MySQLdb.connect(host=config.mysql_host,                                       
                                           user=config.mysql_user,                                       
                                           passwd=config.mysql_pass,                                     
                                           **kwargs)                                                     
        self._cursor = self._connection.cursor()                                                         

    def query(self, query_str):                                                                          
        self._cursor.execute(query_str)                                                                  
        self._connection.commit()                                                                        
        return self._cursor.fetchall()   

    def columns(self, database, table):                                                                  
        return [x[0] for x in self.query('DESCRIBE `%s`.`%s`' % (database, table))g]                      

    def primary_keys(self, database, table):                                                             
        return [x[0] for x in self.query('DESCRIBE `%s`.`%s`' % (database, table)) if 'PRI' in x]
```

And here is the actual update function, using the SQL wrapper class above:

```
def update_table(database, 
                 table,
                 mysql_insert_with_dbtable_placeholder):                                                                            
    '''update a mysql table without first deleting all the old records                                                                 

    mysql_insert_with_dbtable_placeholder should be set to a string with                                                               
    placeholders for database and table, something like:                                                                               

    mysql_insert_with_dbtable_placeholder = "                                                                                          
    INSERT INTO `%(database)s`.`%(table)s` VALUES (a, b, c);                                                           

    note: code as is will update all the non-primary keys, structure                                                                   
    your tables accordingly                                                                                                            
    '''                                                                                                                                
    sql = SimpleSQLConn()                                                                                                              
    query ='DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `%(database)s`.`%(table)s_temp_for_update`' %\                                                        
        {'database': database, 'table': table}                                                                                         
    sql.query(query)                                                                                                                   
    query ='CREATE TABLE `%(database)s`.`%(table)s_temp_for_update` LIKE `%(database)s`.`%(table)s`'%\                                 
        {'database': database, 'table': table}                                                                                         
    sql.query(query)                                                                                                                   
    query = mysql_insert_with_dbtable_placeholder %\                                                                                   
        {'database': database, 'table': '%s_temp_for_update' % table}                                                                  
    sql.query(query)                                                                                                                   
    query = '''DELETE FROM `%(database)s`.`%(table)s` WHERE                                                                            
       (%(primary_keys)s) NOT IN                                                                                                       
       (SELECT %(primary_keys)s FROM `%(database)s`.`%(table)s_temp_for_update`);                                                      
       ''' % {'database': database,                                                                                                    
              'table': table,                                                                                                          
              'primary_keys': ', '.join(['`%s`' % key for key in sql.primary_keys(database, table)])}                                  

    sql.query(query)                                                                                                                   
    update_columns = [col for col in sql.columns(database, table)                                                                      
                      if col not in sql.primary_keys(database, table)]                                                                 
    query = '''INSERT into `%(database)s`.`%(table)s`                                                                                  
    SELECT * FROM `%(database)s`.`%(table)s_temp_for_update`                                                                           
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE                                                                                                            
    %(update_cols)s                                                                                                                    
    ''' %  {'database': database,                                                                                                      
            'table': table,                                                                                                            
            'update_cols' : ',\n'.join(['`%(table)s`.`%(col)s` = `%(table)s_temp_for_update`.`%(col)s`' \                              
                                      % {'table': table, 'col': col} for col in update_columns])}                                      
    sql.query(query)
```